# How to read .XRX file

Tags: c#

In my current project I am required to read a .XRX file and then convert it to .EOB file. Please let me know, using C#, how can I read .XRX file or .EOB file for that matters. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What on Earth are `.XRX` and `.EOB` file types?

Comment: We are getting one .XRX file with a batch of .tiff files. This .XRX file contains the information of batch files. I myself is trying to read a .XRX file for the first time.

Comment: Are they plain text files? What do the contents look like? What have you tried so far in terms of reading them?

Answer (score -1):

Previously when I asked this question I wasn't having XRX file to do R&D with. Now when I have the XRX file, I can confirm that you can read the XRX and EOB file like any other text file using C#. Thank you.